# How to use MSSQL, rebuild all indexes on all tables? MSSQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, fragmentation

I have a mssql database, we'll call it: mssqlDB01. I've been tasked with performing defragmentation on all of the tables. This database has a few hundred tables and each table has a range of 1 to 15 indexes per table.

Google led me to discover a practice to defrag all indexes per table, but I can't figure out how to do it on all tables.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON TABLENAME REBUILD;
```

what i'm looking for is

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON * REBUILD;
```

but it complains

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '*'.`
```

below lets me find all tables in my DB

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

can I somehow push this into the command?

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'; ) REBUILD;
```

Comment: `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505775/rebuild-all-indexes-in-a-database

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could probably write a script that uses dynamic SQL to do that, but why do that when you can use someone else's?  [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/) are the best known and free, but [Minion Ware also has a free reindex script](http://minionware.net/reindex/).

If you insist on writing it yourself, something like this might work:

```
Use mssqlDB01

Declare @TBname nvarchar(255),
        @schema nvarchar(255),
        @SQL nvarchar(max) 


select @TBname = min(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
select @schema = SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' and TABLE_NAME = @TBname

while @TBname is not null
BEGIN
    set @SQL='ALTER INDEX ALL ON [' + @schema + '].[' + @TBname + '] REBUILD;'
    --print @SQL
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    select @TBname = min(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
    select @schema = SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' and TABLE_NAME = @TBname      
END
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Press Ctrl + T
2. Run this query:

   ```
   SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + table_name + '  REBUILD;' 
       FROM Information_Schema.tables where  table_type ='BASE TABLE'
   ```
3. Copy the output and paste it into the SQL window, then click on run.

Comment: It would be good to add "[" and "]" before and after the table (I can't add it as a change need to have 6 chars)

Answer (score 2):

*Building on @Firdaus nice and simple answer:*

If your database has schemas, try running the following in SSMS:

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + table_name + '  REBUILD;' 
    FROM Information_Schema.tables where  table_type ='BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally DBAs create an automated function or have tools to rebuild the indexes.

This one is a functional version to rebuild all indexes to all tables in your schema:

```tsql
DECLARE @tableSchema varchar(max), 
        @tableName varchar(max),
        @tsql nvarchar(max);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM Information_Schema.tables where  table_type ='BASE TABLE'

OPEN cur 

FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @tableSchema, @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @tsql ='ALTER INDEX ALL ON [' + @tableSchema + '].[' + @tableName + '] REBUILD;'
    PRINT(@tsql)
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @tsql;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @tableSchema, @tableName
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 0):

This will rebuild the indexes and keep the compression settings if you have any:

```
DECLARE
    @schemaName sysname,
    @tableName sysname,
    @compressionType VARCHAR(50),
    @sql NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT
    SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName,
    t.name AS TableName,
    p.data_compression_desc AS CompressionType
FROM
    sys.partitions AS p
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE
    p.index_id IN (0, 1)

OPEN table_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor
INTO @schemaName, @tableName, @compressionType

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON [' + @schemaName + '].[' + @tableName + '] REBUILD'
        + CASE WHEN @compressionType <> 'NONE' 
            THEN ' PARTITION = ALL WITH(DATA_COMPRESSION = ' + @compressionType + ')'
            ELSE ''
          END

    PRINT @sql
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor   
    INTO @schemaName, @tableName, @compressionType
END

CLOSE table_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```